# PicketLink protection stops JSF 2.2 resource contract from being loaded

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-2.2, wildfly, picketlink, resource-contracts

I have a JSF 2.2 webapp with a contract and several pages, located directly in the WebContent folder. The contract consists of an image, a template file **template.xhtml** and a css file **global.css**. So far everything is working as expected.

Now I want to use PicketLink for user authentication and authorization and have followed a tutorial (http://www.ocpsoft.org/security/simple-java-ee-jsf-login-page-with-jboss-picketlink-security/), but when accessing my pages the image and css files are unable to be loaded, only the template applies, so my page has no CSS styles applied at all and in the Firefox Inspector there is a line that reads (translated from German): "Stylesheet http://localhost:8080/MyTestProject/login.xhtml wasn't loaded because its MIME type is "text/html" and not "text/css"".

After replacing

```
builder.http().allPaths().authenticateWith().form()... and so on
```

in the **HttpSecurityConfiguration** class with

```
builder.http().allPaths().unprotected()
```

the image and css can be loaded again.

I have tried the following (and some other paths) but it did not solve the problem:

```
.forPath("/contracts/*").unprotected();
```

**How can I exclude the contracts folder from the PicketLink protection?**

---

Here is my complete HttpSecurityConfiguration class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class HttpSecurityConfiguration {

    public void onInit(@Observes SecurityConfigurationEvent event) {

    SecurityConfigurationBuilder builder = event.getBuilder();

    builder
    .http()
    .allPaths()
    .authenticateWith()
    .form()
    .loginPage("/login.xhtml")
    .errorPage("/loginError.xhtml")
    .restoreOriginalRequest()
    .forPath("/logout")
    .logout()
    .redirectTo("/index.xhtml")
    .forPath("/index.xhtml")
    .unprotected()
    //      .forPath("/contracts/*")
    //      .unprotected()
    ;
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
In reply to the comment from Kukeltje, I include the CSS in the template with

```
<h:head>
   <title><ui:insert name="title">MyTestProject</ui:insert></title>
   <h:outputStylesheet name="global.css" />
</h:head>
```

and the image with

```
<h:graphicImage class="feature" name="logo-main.png" width="900" height="270" />
```

I also tried to include **javax.faces.resource** as unprotected, still not working though.

**EDIT #2**
The following is also not working, I got the idea from the documentation ([PicketLink Reference Chapter 12.2](http://docs.jboss.org/picketlink/2/latest/reference/html/sect-Configuration17.html)):

```
.forPath("/*.png").unprotected()
.forPath("/*.css").unprotected()
```

Comment: Excluding a subfolder with resources works for me when I needed a PrimeFaces based login pages where the resources had to be unprotected. The folder was javax.faces.resource instead of your 'contracts' (assuming your css was in there). Maybe there is something wrong in your xhtml or template. Please post those to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem with the following security configuration:

```
.forPath("/javax.faces.resource/*.png.xhtml").unprotected()
```

I've seen in my Firefox Inspector that the browser tried to load the image from `/MyTestProject/javax.faces.resource/logo-main.png.xhtml?con=TemplateBlue`, so trying the above seemed logical and it works!